# Implement C# Linq Distinct Help in order to group a column in table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
private void GetRecDept() 
{
    cmbDept.Items.Clear();
    ListViewMeasurements.Items.Clear();
    SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext();
    try
    {
        var query = (from i in SFC.Systems_SettingsMeasurements
                     orderby i.RowID descending
                     select new { 
                        RowID = i.RowID,
                        Measure = i.Measurement,
                        Target = i.TargetPercentage,
                        Dept = i.Department_ID                                
                     });
        foreach (var w in query) 
        {
           ListViewItem List = new ListViewItem(w.RowID.ToString());
           List.SubItems.Add(w.Measure);
           List.SubItems.Add(string.Format("{0:n2}", w.Target));
           List.SubItems.Add(w.Dept);
           ListViewMeasurements.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { List });
        }
        foreach (var r in query) 
       {
            cmbDept.Items.Add(r.Dept.Distinct());
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   { 
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); 
   }
}
```

Its output on the `cmbDept.Items.Add()` is showing this kind of string 
`System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__7a`1[System.Char]` unlike
in the listview how can i convert it to a string type readable to
users it's in a combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var distinctDept = query.Select(x=>x.Dept).Distinct().ToArray();
cmbDept.Items.AddRange(distinctDept)
```

About your issue, the `Dept` is string, when you use `cmbDept.Items.Add(r.Dept.Distinct());` the added item is an `IEnumerable<char>` and of course it can't display that as you expected, the `ToString()` is called before displaying the `IEnumerable<char>` and gives you the result as you described.